# How to Detect a New Chrome Session in Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, startup

I have an extension that needs to detect when a new Chrome session has started. I found a post here that suggested the following:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(async function() {
   console.log("new startup detected");
   await chrome.storage.local.set({"status":false});
});
```

However, it seems that the listener does not work. It is also not clear what startup it refers to. Start up of Chrome or startup of the extension. Can someone clarify how to detect when a new chrome has started? TIA.

**Updated Code**

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(async function() {
   console.log("new startup detected");
   await chrome.storage.local.set({"status":false});
});
```

**Updated withj Manifest**

```
{
   "manifest_version": 3,

   "name": "Auto_Select",
   "description": "This extension auto selects Mturk HITs",
   "version": "1.0.12",

   "action": {
     "default_icon": "auto_select.png",
     "type": "module",
     "default_popup": "auto_select.html"
   },
   "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "activeTab",
     "storage",
     "contextMenus",
     "tts"
   ],
   "host_permissions": [
      "<all_urls>"
   ],
   "background": {
   "service_worker": "auto_select.js"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
     "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self'"
  }
}
```

Comment: `chrome.storage.session` should solve your problem, if I understand it correctly. Check if a dummy key exists, and it not, create it.

Comment: What exactly does "Chrome session" mean in your extension? It's a very overloaded term.

Comment: I mean a new execution of Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to detect the start of a new session, and you want to detect it in the service worker.

That's why you should use the aptly named [chrome.storage.session](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-session)

The following extension gets and sets a dummy key in `chrome.storage.session` to detect the start of a new session.

How to verify that the extension works correctly:

1. Load the extension
2. Inspect the service worker.
3. The console should show the text "session has started".
4. Close the DevTools window, so the service worker won't stay active.
5. Wait for the service worker to become inactive.
6. Inspect the service worker again.
7. The console should now show the text "session is already running".
8. If you close Chrome and open it again, the service worker console should again show the text "session has started".

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Detect Session Start",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```

background.js

```
(async () => {
    let { started } = await chrome.storage.session.get("started");
    if (started === undefined) {
        console.log("session has started");
        await chrome.storage.session.set({ started: true });
    }
    else {
        console.log("session is already running");
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **chrome.windows.onCreated**.

**chrome.runtime.onStartup**

> Fired when a profile that has this extension installed first starts up.

**chrome.windows.onCreated**

> Fired when a window is created.

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some example code?

Comment: I've updated the OP with your suggestion. Unfortunately it now seems to hang but I'm not sure where since the console is empty. I'm wondering if it is the async that is causing it.

Comment: @Wt Riker, I edited my answer. Please post your manifest.json.

Comment: OP was updated with Manifest.

Comment: @Wt Riker, I used your manifest.json, but it works normally in my environment.
Try it with my manifest.json.

Comment: Thanks I think I have it using chrome.storage.session.